# How to work with generic routes and "mount" them into larger servant apps?

Tags: haskell, servant

### Concept

I've borrowed ["mount" from the Rails world.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#mounting-the-engine) Here's what I'm **conceptually** trying to do:

- Write a mini web-app in Servant, which others can "include/mount" in larger Servant apps
- They should be able to specify a "mount point" for URLs of this mini-app (basically a URL prefix). They should also be able to specify authentication to access this mini-app (highly recommended!)
- Various `safeLinks` used within this mini-app should respect this "mount-point" (else all links would end-up being 404).

### Specifics

And here are the **specifics:**

I've got a [bunch of Servant routes in the `odd-jobs` library](https://github.com/saurabhnanda/odd-jobs/blob/00373ae326e3844c74708dec47212caa6cabef95/src/OddJobs/Web.hs#L102-L110) that look like this:

```hs
data Routes route = Routes
  { rFilterResults :: route :- QueryParam "filters" Filter :> Get '[HTML] (Html ())
  , rStaticAssets :: route :- "assets" :> Raw
  , rEnqueue :: route :- "enqueue" :> Capture "jobId" JobId :> Post '[HTML] NoContent
  , rRunNow :: route :- "run" :> Capture "jobId" JobId :> Post '[HTML] NoContent
  , rCancel :: route :- "cancel" :> Capture "jobId" JobId :> Post '[HTML] NoContent
  , rRefreshJobTypes :: route :- "refresh-job-types" :> Post '[HTML] NoContent
  , rRefreshJobRunners :: route :- "refresh-job-runners" :> Post '[HTML] NoContent
  } deriving (Generic)
```

I have a separate [`OddJobs.Links` module](https://github.com/saurabhnanda/odd-jobs/blob/00373ae326e3844c74708dec47212caa6cabef95/src/OddJobs/Links.hs) that uses the `RecordWildCards` trick to get a bunch of safe-link generation functions in the top-level namespace:

```hs
Routes{..} = allFieldLinks' absText :: Routes (AsLink Text)

absText :: Link -> Text
absText l = "/" <> (toS $ show $ linkURI l)
```

The HTML generated by the job-queue's web-ui uses these top-level function [as such](https://github.com/saurabhnanda/odd-jobs/blob/00373ae326e3844c74708dec47212caa6cabef95/src/OddJobs/Endpoints.hs#L403):

```hs
form_ [ action_ (Links.rCancel jobId), method_ "post" ] $ do
```

### Questions

- I've been staring at `safeLink`, and related functions, in [Servant.Links](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.6/servant-0.16.2/Servant-Links.html#g:1) and am unable to figure out if `safeLink`'s first argument basically figures out the "mount-point" automatically, or not? If it does, what would be the corresponding way to use `fieldLink` (and related functions)?
- How do you "combine" multiple APIs, each defined with a generic-record, such that you can generate safe-link functions (and servant-clients) for the combined API?
- Will my HTML generation functions basically need to accept the "mount-point" as an argument, generate the safe-link functions, and them pass them around everywhere? i.e. I won't be able to use the `RecordWildCards` trick to get these functions in the top-level namespace, right?
- What will happen to my actual handlers, if the user of my library decides to add basic-auth while combining this mini-app into a larger servant app?

Comment: I can't quite put together how to parameterize the main API but this was helpful to me in solving a similar issue: https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/1040